# Using differentials to find the maximum error that a diameter can have so that the area error is within $1\%$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am given the following problem:

> The area of a circle was computed using the measurement of its
>   diameter. Use differentials to find the maximum error that a diameter
>   can have so that the area error is within $1\%$

What I have so far is

$$
A = \pi r^2 = \frac{\pi d^2}{4}\\
\\
\frac{dA}{dd} = \frac{\pi}{4} 2d\\
dA = \frac{\pi}{2} d \ dd\\
dd = \frac{0.1 d}{2} = 0.05 \cdot d = 5\% \cdot d
$$

So the answer would be $5\%$.

Is that correct? Am I missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: You lost a $0$, $1/100=0.01$ not $0.1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area, given the diameter, is
$$A(d) = \frac{\pi d^2}{4}.$$
Therefore
$$A(d+\Delta d) = \frac{\pi}{4}(d^2+2d\Delta d + \Delta d^2).$$
If the (I assume, relative) area error is less than $1\%$,
$$0.01 \leq \left|\frac{A(d+\Delta d)-A(d)}{A(d)}\right| = \left|\frac{2d\Delta d + \Delta d^2}{d^2}\right|$$

The diameter error is
$$E = \left|\frac{d + \Delta d - d}{d}\right| = \left|\frac{\Delta d}{d}\right|$$
so that
$$0.01 \leq 2 E + E^2.$$

Now can you find which values of $E$ satisfy the inequality?